Server cron will not trigger wp-cron, none of the advice and code snippets available actually work
Goal:
The goal is to ensuring that each task runs concurrently without being queued or delayed. I have several cron jobs set up on my site, each scheduled to run every minute. However, I would like to ensure that all of these cron jobs can execute at the same time without any delays or performance issues.
Issue:
My parallel cron jobs aren’t working.

All the jobs have been successfully created in my database, but they stop executing as they should.


When calling the REST API manually, it works as well.



What i followed:

I started by installing the Automatic Cron Control plugin from GitHub. I installed the plugin from Automatic Cron Control

After the plugin was installed, I configured the settings to disable the default WP Cron and added the secret key to wp-config.php file:



define( 'WP_CRON_CONTROL_SECRET', '85bf6fefd2bd1825023f8b5e5c98e112' );
define( 'DISABLE_WP_CRON', true );


Next, I set up a cron job on my server to trigger WordPress cron jobs at a specified interval (e.g., every minute).  and there are 2 crons running on the server :


This cron job will trigger Automatic Cron Control plugin's main root file


 * * * * * php /home/public_html/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/cron-control/cron-control.php 


This cron job calls the wp-cron.php file on my WordPress site


* * * * * wget -q -O - "https://domain.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron&85bf6fefd2bd1825023f8b5e5c98e112" > /dev/null 2>&1


Once the cron job was set up, I manually tested the endpoint to ensure that the cron jobs were being triggered correctly:


https://domain.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron&85bf6fefd2bd1825023f8b5e5c98e112


Hello Komal - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! It sounds like these issues and misbehaviors are highly specific to this "Automatic Cron Control" plugin. You should pose this question to it's support channels, or associated/more general communities; questions about third-party extensions are off-topic here.

this sounds like you decided on a solution, and most likely the solution do not fit the problem you are trying to solve. in general there is no such thing as simultanecy in software. you might get close to it if you can run processes on different cores or maybe different computers but even then in real life some queues are likely to be needed. Specifically php is not built to be able to run same code in the same time without curroption, and wordpress's cron has defences against curroption at higher layers (DB and object cache access) and the defences will requires queues.

bypassing the defence can lead to data curroption and no one wants to get there even if the chances for that to happen are relatively low

I want to know the answer because we have been trying to get this to work for a while, all of these websites say it will work, and it has never worked - we have never been able to get the server cron to trigger wp-cron.
